# How to set $_SESSION variable when click on a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

In my portfolio I implemented a PHP script that generate some div that contain images of some works.
When users click on a div, there is a redirect on a details.php page that contains work details. How can I set $_SESSION variable values, in order to use them on details.php?

PHP scipt:

```
$query2="SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Category='".$record1['Category']."' ORDER BY data_pubb DESC";
            $esito2 = mysql_query($query2);
            while($record2 = mysql_fetch_array($esito2))
            {
                echo "
                    <div class='col-sm-4 job'>
                        <div class='container hover-image-container'>
                            <a href=''>
                                <img src='".$record2['static_img']."' data-src='".$record2['static_img']."' data-animated-src='".$record2['dinamic_img']."' width='100%' height='100%' />
                                <div class='overlay'>
                                    <div class='text'>".$record2['title']."</div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        ";
            }
```

Comment: you start the session  and in all pages using them while assign a session array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use JavaScript to detect the `onclick` and use `AJAX` to start the session.

For starters, add `session_start();` to the top of your page.

Then add an `onclick` event to your div:

```
<div class='col-sm-4 job' onclick='startsession()`>
```

Then define the `startsession()` function:

```
function startsession() {
   $.ajax({
      var name = ''; // the name of your session e.g $_SESSION['counters'];
      var value = ''; // the value of your session e.g 10
      url: "sessionstart.php",
      data: {session: name, value: value},
      success: function(data){
         // your success function
      }
   });
}
```

Then on `sessionstart.php`:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_POST['name'] = $_POST['value'];
<?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
//Set session
$name = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['user'] = $name;
//Fetch session
echo $_SESSION['user'];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can perform an AJAX Request on click of the div. Pass the data in this request that you want to set in the Session variable. Once you get the response back you can then visit the details.php and access the Session variable that got set.

For onclick either you can set

```
<div ... onclick="functionName()" ></div>
```

Or, set an ID or class and attach an event listener to it.

```
<div id="myDiv">...</div>
$('#myDiv').on('click',function(){
   //perform the ajax request here.
});
```

Comment: Can i know the reason for down voting my answer?